# Can I get a specific value of the proximity sensor in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sensors, proximity

I am currently trying to make an iOS version of an android app, which collects sensor data. And I am having a problem on getting a specific value of the proximity sensor in Swift.

While `TYPE_PROXIMITY` in Android returns an int type value of distance from object in cm unit, `CLProximity` of Swift only returns enum values telling whether the distance is far or near.

I'm pretty sure that there must be also a way to get the specific value in Swift since it is available in Android... but I can't find a way.

reference:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_PROXIMITY
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clproximity

Comment: Maybe try the rssi

Comment: There is not a way to get a distance measurement in iOS since it tends to be wildly inaccurate.  As  @aheze said you can try and infer a distance from the rssi but this will also be wildly inaccurate. 2.4gHz BLE signals are absorbed by bodies very well and so the positioning of the person relative to the beacon has a significant effect.

Comment: @Paulw11 But how is it possible to get such an accurate value in Android phones? TYPE_PROXIMITY gives proximity sensor distance measured in centimeters. Is iPhone using a different proximity sensor?

Comment: Looking at the Android documentation you are comparing different things. The proximity sensor on Android is a sensor built in to the device, that measures the proximity of the users face or a hand to the device https://ssaurel.medium.com/learn-to-create-a-proximity-detector-app-on-android-2064858e840a . The iOS documentation you have linked to is the proximity of a Bluetooth iBeacon

Comment: @Paulw11 Ohh I get it. Then will this be the right comparison? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620058-proximitystate?language=objc

Comment: Yes, that is the equivalent sensor on iOS.